# Activating theme in local MAMP installation results in HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: theme-development, localhost, local-installation

I have a local WordPress installation in a MAMP server that was working fine and after a period of time without using it I come back to it and I get a HTTP ERROR 500. Couldn't figure out how to fix it so I decided to install WordPress again but after activating the theme it broke again. I also tried a fresh MAMP install and again after activating the theme I get a 500 error.

How can I find what's causing this? I have the theme installed in the client's server and working fine here: http://marilimitado.com/

Comment: error 500 is Apache/Nginx saying it encountered an error in PHP, and that you should look into the PHP error logs, its the equivalent of "it's broken" but with no details or explanation

Comment: Thanks for your comment @TomJNowell. The only thing I found was this, in a error_log file

[24-Jan-2016 14:18:58 Europe/Paris] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/marilimi/public_html/wp/wp-content/themes/marilimitado/index.php on line 1

Comment: That will be the actual error you should be looking into